# How to configure HTTPS for Tomcat on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, https

I have an instance on AWS with Tomcat that works on `80` port.
My security groups has following configuration:
[image]

I did do configuration for Tomcat and keytool. On local machine it works and I can do `https://localhost:8443`, but how can I open HTTPS for port `8443` on AWS?

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
       keystoreFile="/home/user/keytools/ssl"
       keystorePass="123456"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just change Connector port=443 it will work.

Comment: Will I need to bind 443 port?

Comment: yes you need to bind this port. When you browse https site, browser will directly call 443 port.